# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric in view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a view:

```
SELECT
u.display_name AS usuario,
g.parent_name AS grupo,
pr.pkey,
REPLACE(
    CONVERT (VARCHAR, ji.CREATED, 111),
    '/',
    '-'
) AS fecha,
CAST (ji.issuetype AS INT) AS issuetype,
a.customvalue AS aplicativo,
m.customvalue AS modulo
FROM
jiraissue AS ji
JOIN project pr ON pr.ID = ji.PROJECT
JOIN (
SELECT
    ms.*
FROM
    cwd_membership ms
INNER JOIN cwd_group gp ON (
    gp.ID = ms.parent_id
    AND group_name IN (
        'Grupo QA 1',
        'Grupo QA 2',
        'Grupo QA 3',
        'BH Seguros Homo'
    )
)
) g ON g.lower_child_name = ji.REPORTER
JOIN cwd_user u ON g.lower_child_name = u.user_name
JOIN (
SELECT
    ISSUE,
    customvalue
FROM
    customfieldvalue v
INNER JOIN customfield f ON (
    f.ID = v.customfield
    AND f.cfname = 'Aplicativo'
)
INNER JOIN customfieldoption o ON (o.ID = v.STRINGVALUE)
) a ON (a.ISSUE = ji.ID)
JOIN (
SELECT
    ISSUE,
    customvalue
FROM
    customfieldvalue v
INNER JOIN customfield f ON (
    f.ID = v.customfield
    AND f.cfname = 'Módulo'
)
INNER JOIN customfieldoption o ON (o.ID = v.STRINGVALUE)
) m ON (m.ISSUE = ji.ID)
WHERE
ji.issuetype IN (9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
GROUP BY
ji.issuetype,
pr.pkey,
g.parent_name,
u.display_name,
REPLACE(
    CONVERT (VARCHAR, ji.CREATED, 111),
    '/',
    '-'
),
a.customvalue,
m.customvalue
```

And this gives me something like this:

```
usuario             grupo      pkey     fecha       issuetype  aplicativo 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ricardo A. Casares  Grupo QA 1  GD123   2012-11-23  12  Act-creditos-scheduler  ABM_Suc-backend
```

And then, when I try to query this view, let's say a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM view
WHERE pkey LIKE '%GD123%'
```

In some columns I'm getting "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric"
But in some other columns, like "aplicativo" it is working fine.

Why is this happening?

Comment: When are you getting the error, when you run the above query against pkey?  If not, which query is returning that error?

Comment: What type of `jiraissue.issuetype`?

Comment: @user1073631 yes on pkey

Comment: @HamletHakobyan jiraissue.issuetype is nvarchar

Comment: Are you sure, all data from `issuetype` are convertible to `int`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be converted, if not, could be this causing the error?

Comment: Yep, if you run SELECT CAST (ji.issuetype AS INT) AS issuetype FROM jiraissue and receive the same error, then that is your problem.  See answer posted by @Blachshma.

Comment: @user1073631 actually the query you suggest works just fine.

Comment: @ricardocasares You said _"In some columns I'm getting "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric" But in some other columns, like "aplicativo" it is working fine."_ - What do you mean by "some columns"? Which columns??

Comment: For example in grupo and aplicativo works fine, but in everything else fails.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot with an example? You say that `usuario` for instance also shows that error *inside the result of the column*?

Comment: It's pretty weird, as you can see, modulo and aplicativo columns are constructed pretty much the same way.

Comment: Some screenshots
http://snag.gy/rtZRs.jpg
http://snag.gy/2iVA8.jpg
http://snag.gy/CmM6B.jpg

Comment: @Blachshma the definition is the first sql in my question, I'm not sure if this is what you're asking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with this assignment:

```
o.ID = v.STRINGVALUE
```

please correct it and it will solve the issue. A possible way to correct the issue is to use ISNUMERIC, e.g.

```
o.ID = CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(v.STRINGVALUE) = 1 THEN v.STRINGVALUE ELSE -1 END
```

(in the ELSE you can use some other number that is guaranteed to not join with table 'o', i.e. you can use 0)

Comment: OP claims he doesn't have any problems casting the `ji.issuetype` column

Comment: so, it must be o.ID = v.STRINGVALUE is a culprit

Comment: or, it could be this: ji.issuetype IN (9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15). Can you comment this line and re-test?

Comment: @cha removing that line solved the pkey where/like query, but I'm still having trouble with another columns, like usuario

Comment: @cha I think, as you said, the problem is in the o.ID = v.STRINGVALUE portion of my query. Not always this STRINGVALUE is a string representation of an integer.

Comment: @cha How could I correct the query in order to not fail, like using the ISNUMERIC() function?

Answer (score 3):

This error means that you have some column which is of type `nvarchar` and you're trying to make a conversion to a numeric value (int, for instance).
*BUT* in at least on of the rows returned, that value cannot be converter to a numeric.

For example - trying to convert "abcd" to a numeric will raise that error.

In the query you supplied it is probably on the line: `CAST (ji.issuetype AS INT) AS issuetype`

Check if any of the data in `ji.issuetype` is not a string represention of a number...

Comment: Mmm, actually all rows from jiraissue.issuetype are string representation of a number.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can try is to use `ARITHABORT` to tell SQL to just NULL values it cant cast.

For example, using `SET ARITHABORT OFF` & `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` before selecting from the view should NULL the values it fails to cast (instead of throwing exceptions) - you can then see what rows (and in turn what values) are giving you grief.